# Prevent UITableView out of cell bound views from clipping on insertRowsAtIndexPaths:

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, insert, clip

This **video** shows how cells with views extending out of the cell area get clipped momentarily when new cells are being inserted:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22105205/CellClipping.mov

This **simple project** clearly shows the problem and can be used for quick prototyping:

https://github.com/AndresCanella/iOSInsertCellClippingExample.git

- This clipping only occurs when the table is mutated.
- Cells are clear.
- Cells display correctly when not mutating.

Possibly some sort of optimization that only uses pix from within the cell area for animation?

Everything is setup correctly, stable, and works as expected, we are not even using specific cell data for this example:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
self.cells++;
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

**Update:**

Response from DTS:

I’m afraid you are not going to be able to directly affect the insertion animation behavior when calling “insertRowsAtIndexPaths”, regardless of the kind of “UITableViewRowAnimation” you are using.  Cell content conventionally don’t overlap like that.  UITableView is simply honoring the cell’s bounds (not it’s extended or overlapping content), when performing its animation block of each cell.

My comment:

I've been told by DTS that things can be done plenty of times and I've always found a workaround. So now I'm looking for a work around.

Apple Bug Report # 17986466

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the views you wish to not be clipped exceed the bounds of the cells themselves. To me, that says that these should be subviews of the table view instead of the cell.

If that is indeed the case, you may wish to use a plain UIScrollView instead of a UITableView, and animate the the views below the one being inserted downwards.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the first line of the description. I will update the  name to include this as well. The question is for a solution in this scenario. End use is a cell heavy environment, UIScrollView is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you should try to keep the cells with a non-clear/transparent background and set to clip subviews if you want to avoid weird layouts and animation glitches.

The way the cells view hierarchy is set inside the table view and how animations are made is internal to Apple implementation and prone to change without notice in future releases.

---

Table views are good at displaying tons of rows and reusing views, things that maybe your view is not really using. If your desired layout does not require several screens of scrollable content maybe you should try to create your own custom `UIScrollView`-based view or search for one among the many open source libraries. You would have complete control of animations and add custom behaviors.

Comment: Yep, I am very aware that this is not the ideal use but our design requires it. With every build iOS has supported it more and more. Our overlapping has always worked perfectly using reloadData every time, it is just this special case that is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is a complete hack - but it does fix the clipping.

For granular animations - check out PRTWeen.
https://github.com/jdp-global/MWDatePicker

I guess you considered toggling 2 transparent background images (red and green) (640px x100px) on current cell and previous cell? It may work using a fade in animation on insert.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    self.cells++;
    [self.tb reloadData];

    [self performSelector:@selector(fancyAnimate:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0];


}
-(void)fancyAnimate:(NSIndexPath*)path{
    NSIndexPath *idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:path.row inSection:path.section] ;

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.tb cellForRowAtIndexPath:idx];
    CGRect frame = cell.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    cell.frame = frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    cell.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Comment: Time ending, awarded for providing a solution attempt, though not a solution for question "clipping on insertRowsAtIndexPaths:". The user of insertRowsAtIndexPaths: is to get away from using reloadData. That has negative side effects on scrolling, and a lot of little other aspects.

Comment: Thx Andres. N.B. I'm seeing on my device ios 7.0.4 - clipping on every cell (without mutating tableview).  7.1 is fine and simulator is working as expected.

Comment: Indeed. You need to transverse sub cell views and set no clipping prior to 7.1. So that was fixed, which hints at apple supporting overlapping more and more... I've filed a bug report with apple.